# make cv2.imwrite case-sensitve

Tags: python, case-sensitive, opencv

Is it possible to make pythons OpenCV imwrite case sensitve?

As an example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

black_image = np.zeros((10,10,1), np.uint8)
white_image = np.ones((10,10,1), np.uint8)*255

cv2.imwrite("a.png", white_image)
cv2.imwrite("A.png", black_image)
```

I get one black img, called *a.png*.

But I would like to get one white img, *a.png*, and a second black img, *A.png*.

(I am on a mac)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, what you are asking for is impossible.